# Apply the principle of mathematical induction or its variants to show that for all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $0\le m<n$:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

**As the title says**

Apply the principle of mathematical induction or its variants to show that for all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that $0\le m < n$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n}k=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m\,.$$

Not sure, I tried using traditional combinational proofs, but I'm a little lost on where to go.

Comment: There is a basic MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); if you plan to use this set in the future, you’ll want to learn the basics.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could do that or edit other's questions.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Do the induction on $n$. For your induction hypothesis suppose that

$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n}k=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m$$

for all $m$ such that $0\le m<n$; then you want to show that

$$\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n+1}k=(-1)^m\binom{n}m$$

whenever $0\le m<n+1$. For $0\le m<n$ you can follow the usual pattern for such proofs, starting with this:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n+1}k&=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\left(\binom{n}k+\binom{n}{k-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n}k+\sum_{k=0}^m(-1)^k\binom{n}{k-1}\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m+\sum_{k=1}^m(-1)^k\binom{n}{k-1}\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m+\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k\\
&=(-1)^m\binom{n-1}m-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}(-1)^k\binom{n}k\,;
\end{align*}$$

see if you can finish it from there.

The remaining case, $m=n$, has to be handled separately; for now I’ll leave that to you, merely noting that it follows from an application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: (+1) I looked at your answer after I posted, and although a bit simpler, mine was in essence no different.

Comment: If your work was independent, I see no problem in leaving it up.

Comment: @robjohn please provide your solution also.

Comment: was it without the use of priciple of induction?

Comment: @Anonymous: No, it was not. It was essentially the same as mine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok i understood.

Comment: I got the solution also just now

Comment: without the use of PMI

Comment: PMI= principle of mathematical induction